# JavaScript/jQuery: hasDescendant / hasAncestor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, descendant

Hilariously, I'm having incredible difficulty finding any half-good way to determine whether or not an HTML element is inside another one or not -- which seems like it should be a basic core feature of traversing and analyzing the HTML DOM. I was immensely surprised and disappointed that the "hasDescendant" (or likewise) method is missing.

I'm trying to do this:

```
var frog = $('#frog');
var walrus = $('#walrus');
if (frog.hasDescendant(walrus)) console.log("Frog is within walrus.");
else console.log("Frog is outside walrus.");
```

I've tried to reproduce what I'm looking for with many jQuery combinations.

```
walrus.is(frog.parents());
walrus.has(frog);
walrus.find(' *').has(frog);
frog.is(walrus.find(' *'));
```

I haven't found a working solution yet.

---

*[edit]*
**Solution:** `walrus.has(frog)`
**Alternate:** `if (walrus.has(frog)) { doStuff(); }`
**Alternate:** `var booleanResult = walrus.has(frog).length>0;`

---

//Chase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
if (walrus.has(frog).length) {
  // frog is contained in walrus..
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/pZfLm/

---

An alternative

```
if ( $('#frog').closest('#walrus').length ){
      // frog is contained in walrus..
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/pZfLm/1/

Answer (score 4):

jQuery has just the function for this: [`jQuery.contains`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/): *"Check to see if a DOM element is within another DOM element."*

Demo ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/igizuk)):

HTML:

```
<p id="frog">Frog <span id="walrus">walrus</span></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var frog = $("#frog"),
      walrus = $("#walrus");

  display("frog contains walrus? " + $.contains(frog[0], walrus[0]));
  display("walrus contains frog? " + $.contains(walrus[0], frog[0]));

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

Comment: Immediately after reading this answer, I implemented `$.contains` into my project, and was surprised to find that it was failing on me under certain circumstances that I did not expect. I didn't have time to fully figure it out, but I **think** some dynamic content added with `$(element).html(newContent);` was failing to attach itself to the DOM properly (causing HTMLElement.parentNode to == null, furthermore causing `$.contains` to fail). It was creepy because I had `$.contains` returning results that were in direct contradiction with what I could see in the firebug DOM view.

Comment: @ChaseMoskal: See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to write your own function you could do it without jQuery, perhaps something like this:

```
function isAncestor(ancestor, descendent) {
   while ((descendent = descendent.parentNode) != null)
      if (descendent == ancestor)
         return true;

   return false;
}
```